# Return 1 if any even bit is set to 1 using only bitwise and logical operators

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation

I am currently stuck on a function that I need to write that checks if any even numbered bits are set to 1. For example, `evenBit(0x1)` returns 1, `evenBit(0x2)` returns 0, and `evenBit(0xFFFFFFFF)` returns 1. Currently my `evenBit()` function looks like this:

```
unsigned int evenBit(unsigned int x) {
    unsigned int evenMask = 0x55555555;
    return x & evenMask;
}
```

But these aren't returning the results that I was expecting but I'm not entirely sure how to approach this. I want to isolate the even bits with the mask, which I've done, but I'm not sure what to do with the result after so that it will become 1. I can use only bitwise and logical operators (&, |, !); no if statements, loops, arithmetic operators (+, -, *, /, %), or conditional operators (==, !=, etc).

Comment: FYI, `evenMask` is `~0u/3` for any size `unsigned int` that does not use an odd number of bits. So you do not need a hard-coded constant for a specific width, like `0x5555555555`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your posted code is already correct in the sense that the function `evenBit` will return a nonzero value (true) if any of the bits are set, and zero (false) if not.

If you want to restrict the return values to `0` and `1`, then you can change the line

```
return x & evenMask;
```

to:

```
return !!( x & evenMask );
```

This will apply the logical-NOT operator `!` twice.

The logical-NOT operator will evaluate to `0` if its operand is nonzero, and to `1` if its operand is zero. Therefore, this operation gives you the exact opposite of the result that you want. Applying the logical-NOT operator a second time will give you the desired result.

Normally, a programmer would write

```
return ( x & evenMask ) != 0;
```

or

```
return ( x & evenMask ) ? 1 : 0;
```

to achieve the exact same result, however this would violate the restrictions stated in your question of only using bitwise and logical operators.

Comment: Yet another way: `return x & evenMask ? 1 : 0;`

Comment: @ikegami: Yes,  your example is actually better, because it makes clearer that the results should be restricted to `1` and `0`. I have added it to my answer.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel To help clarify for the conditions, I can use only bitwise and logical operators (&&, ||, !); no if statements, loops, arithmetic operators
(+, -, *, /, %), or conditional operators (==, !=, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Using only bitwise operators (and assignments) as requested,

```c
x |= x >> 16;
x |= x >>  8;
x |= x >>  4;
x |= x >>  2;
return x & 1;
```

Like the OP, I assumed `x` is a 32-bit unsigned int, though that isn't guaranteed. An `unsigned int` could be smaller or larger.